# python Input column values from lists

Tags: python, list, dataframe

Consider I have the following data.

```
import pandas as pd

age = [[1,2,3],[2,1],[4,2,3,1],[2,1,3]]

frame = {'age': age } 

result = pd.DataFrame(frame) 

ver=pd.DataFrame(result.age.values.tolist(), index= result.index)
listado=pd.unique(ver.values.ravel('K'))

cleanedList = [x for x in listado if str(x) != 'nan']

for col in cleanedList:
    result[col] = 0

#Return values
 age         1.0    2.0 4.0 3.0
[1, 2, 3]      0    0   0   0
[2, 1]         0    0   0   0
[4, 2, 3, 1]   0    0   0   0
[2, 1, 3]      0    0   0   0
```

How can I impute 1 in the columns corresponding to each list in the age column. So final output would be:

```
 age         1.0    2.0 4.0 3.0
[1, 2, 3]      1    1   0   1
[2, 1]         1    1   0   0
[4, 2, 3, 1]   1    1   1   1
[2, 1, 3]      1    1   1   0
```

Consider that the amount of elements in the age column is dynamic (as an example I put 4 numbers, but in reality they can be many more).

Comment: You haven't defined `author` or `article`

Comment: Sorry, not important columns. Already edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check with `sklearn`

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import MultiLabelBinarizer
mlb = MultiLabelBinarizer()
s=pd.DataFrame(mlb.fit_transform(result['age']),columns=mlb.classes_, index=result.index)
s
   1  2  3  4
0  1  1  1  0
1  1  1  0  0
2  1  1  1  1
3  1  1  1  0
#df = df.join(s)
```

Comment: Oh so genious!!